# QEMU Win10 resolution change doesn't work when window resized

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, qemu

I have VM with Windows 10 as guest and would like to set up automatic resolution change when window (qemu integrated display or virt-viewer) is resized, but it doesn't work for me.
My virtual machine:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 
-machine q35 
-nodefaults 
-enable-kvm 
-cpu host 
-smp cores=2,threads=1 
-m 4G 
-drive file=win10.img,format=raw,if=virtio 
-net nic,model=virtio
-net user 
-vga virtio 
-device virtio-mouse 
-device virtio-keyboard
```

I have guest additions and all relevant virtio drivers installed.

I tried both integrated qemu display and virt-viewer, and in both the resolution change when window resized doesn't work.
Also tried to add:

```
-device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0 
-chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel1,name=vdagent 
-device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=2,chardev=charchannel1,id=channel1,name=com.redhat.spice.0
```

because somewhere I read that guest needs to communicate through that serial device to be able to resize resolution when needed, but it doesn't work with it too.

I also tried Linux guest (Linux Lite 6.4), and there it works flawlessly through qemu integrated display, even when boot animation is shown, but doesn't with virt-viewer through spice.
On qemu display resizing works without that chardev i mentioned above (with Linux Lite as guest).

Answer (score 0):

Virgl does not work on windows. Just use virtio-gpu or qxl, both have similar performance.

You need to install virtio drivers, you can get them from redhat's website in iso format, just pass that through to the guest, or download the files on the guest and extract/mount the iso and install the drivers.